# css effect on hover, on achor tag with image

Tags: css, tags, hover, anchor

for my site I have finally created a load more option, with a clickable image that when clicked loads the next posts.
However, I want to add an effect to the image so when one hovers over the "plus" spins. Since the link area is above the image the "plus" no longer spins.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this without potentially breaking the plugin, behind this load more function in wordpress ?

```css
a.load_more { border-radius: 70%; height:26%; width:15%; position: absolute; top:3%; left:1.5%; display:block; background:rgba(0,255,0,0.5);}

img.plus{
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform .8s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
    z-index:999
}

img.plus:hover{
    transform:rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
    <div id="content">
        <div id="block">     
            <div>
                <img class="plus" src="http://www.hellodolly.be/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/plus.png"/>
                <a href="#" class="load_more"></a>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div><!--/content-->
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aoxg9knj/)

Answer (score 1):

you can put the link around the image so the image is the link you dont even need a class for the href then.

example:

```
 <div id="content">
        <div id="block">     
            <div>
               <a href="#" class="load_more">
                <img class="plus" src="http://www.hellodolly.be/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/plus.png"/>
               </a>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div><!--/content-->
```

I hope that i have understand you're question correct and that this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try to add "visibility: hidden"

```
.load_more { 
  border-radius: 70%; 
  height:29%; 
  width:11%; 
  position: absolute; 
  top:3%; left:1.2%; 
  display:block; 
  background:rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your markup into like this. Wrap the image by anchor.

```css
img.plus{
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform .8s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
    z-index:999
}

img.plus:hover{
    transform:rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
        <div id="block">     
            <div>
                <a href="#" class="load_more"><img class="plus" src="http://www.hellodolly.be/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/plus.png"/></a>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div><!--/content-->
```

Hope it helps. Cheers

Comment: Hi, this worked fine, however I now have a problem with it's responsiveness with smaller resolutions, such as for the phone. The image stays the same size, regardless trying to make the window smaller. Might adding another <div> work ?

Comment: If you use bootstrap. Putting class img-responsive would do the trick.